# Nginx - как изменить URL в адресной строке?

Tags: nginx, сервер, url, rewrite

Помогите решить задачу.
Хочу сделать красивый короткий адрес в строке браузера и скрыть /blog/post/ 
Файлы расположены в /blog/post/ их я двигать не буду.
Например вместо: 
https://site.com/blog/post/world.html 
https://site.com/world.html

```
location / {
       if ($query_string ~ "^$"){
       rewrite ^/blog/post/world\.html$ /world.html? break;
    }
}
```

Вероятно rewrite не подходящий вариант, в общем не знаю как реализовать.

```
location = /world.html {
            rewrite .* /blog/post/world.html break;
        }
      
        
        location = /blog/post/world.html {
            return 301 /world.html ;
        }
```

Comment: Дока отличнейшая у NGINX ( https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias ) [alias] и ( https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files ) [try_files] глянь, там всё ровно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После сабмита ваше приложение должно направить пользователя на адрес `/wordld.html`.

А в nginx добавьте rewrite:

```
location = /world.html {
    rewrite .* /blog/post/world.html last;
}
```

Таким образом в браузере будет адрес `/wordld.html`,

а фактически будет отдаваться файл, размещенный по пути: `/var/www/site.com/blog/post/world.html`

конечно же при условии что вы указали `root /var/www/site.com`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает при запросе site.com/world.html )

Comment: Можно в теории сделать так еще? Eсли юзер ввел в бразуер site.com/blog/post/world.html, мне тогда нужно делать редирект на sitel.com/world.htm где в свою очередь будет срабатывать location = /world.html

Comment: Еще вопрос, как лучше сделать, если юзер руками ввел например site.com/blog/post нужно что бы его не пускало туда, как это лучше сделать редиректом на главную или как то закрыть доступ? Идея в том что-бы доступа каталогу /blog/ и /blog/post/  в ручную не было.

Comment: Похоже зацикливание выйдет если редиректить на location = /world.html а он в свою очередь обратиться по полному пути а там опять редирект.

Comment: Я разобрался, ну походу выглядит это убого, вероятно можно сделать лучше, пока это на костыль похоже, но работает. При запросе полного адреса я получаю коротки. Скину выше в вопросе что у меня получилоь.